# pyspark df.write.format("jdbc") grant statement DB2

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, db2, apache-zeppelin

I want add a command to add my grant statement so i can provide Select access to users to the table i have loaded using pyspark.

```
  df.write.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:db2:@//<host>:<port>/<srvice_name") \
    .option("user", "<user>") \
    .option("password", "<pass>") \
    .option("dbtable", db_query) \
    .option("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")
```

Comment: Your subject-line and keywords mention Db2, but you show only Oracle url and Oracke driver. EDIT your question to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking for options within pyspark. Don't know if it's possible using pyspark. You can do it using other database access methods like SQL Alchemy.

[How to grant access privileges to DB2 table using SQLAlchemy in a jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599535/how-to-grant-access-privileges-to-db2-table-using-sqlalchemy-in-a-jupyter-notebo)